# Using jQuery plugins with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using the [latest version of RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) and trying to get it to work with jQuery and jQuery plugins.

I can get it to load jQuery fine, but I can't get it to work with jQuery plugins. This is my code:

```
 var dependencies = ["order!jquery"];
 dependencies = dependencies.concat([
   "order!plugins/underscore-1.3.1", 
   "order!plugins/backbone-0.9.1", 
   "order!plugins/jquery.typewatch"]); 
require.config({
  waitSeconds: 30,
  paths: {
      "jquery": 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1'
  }
});

require(dependencies, function($) {
   ...
```

jQuery is loading OK, but I then get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined     jquery.typewatch.js:92
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function    backbone-0.9.1.js:1064
```

The first error is complaining about `jQuery` not being defined, and the second about `$` not being defined.

Why isn't this working? Everything seems to be loading in the right order, the order plugin works OK for underscore and backbone, and I can use `$` in the code for normal jQuery functions.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756567/loading-jquery-plugins-with-require-js

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756567/loading-jquery-plugins-with-require-js actually have an answer?

Comment: The order plugin is not supported in current versions of requirejs, it has been superseded by the feature used in the answer of the linked question.  Read more about the change **[here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#shim-config-)** and **[here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)**.